# I wrote an asynchronous class, but I don't kown how to optimize it

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I wrote an asynchronous class which can run the function asynchronously, well, the fact is the class is very ugly, see below:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AsyncLibery
{
public class AsyncLib
{
    public AsyncLib() { }

    public AsyncLib(Object myObject)
    {
        this.MyObject = myObject;
    }

    public Object MyObject { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// No Parameter,WithOut ReturnValue
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionFunction">the function needed to be delegated</param>
    public void Async(Action actionFunction)
    {
        Form form = (MyObject as Form);
        form.Invoke((Action)(() => actionFunction()));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// No parameter, With returnValue
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="funcFunction">the function needed to be delegated</param>
    /// <returns>return object type</returns>
    public object AsyncWithReturnValue(Func<object> funcFunction)
    {
        object returnValue = null;
        Form form = (MyObject as Form);
        form.Invoke(new Func<object>(delegate()
        {
            returnValue = funcFunction();
            return returnValue;
        }));
        return returnValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// One Parameter, With ReturnValue
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="funcFunction">the function needed to be delegated</param>
    /// <param name="inputValue">the input parameter</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object AsyncWithReturnValue(Func<object, object> funcFunction, object inputValue)
    {
        object returnValue = null;
        Form form = (MyObject as Form);
        form.Invoke(new Func<object,object>(delegate(object _object)
        {
            returnValue = funcFunction(_object);
            return returnValue;
        }),inputValue);
        return returnValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Two Parameters , With ReturnValue
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="funcFunction">the function needed to be delegated</param>
    /// <param name="inputValue1">the first input parameter</param>
    /// <param name="inputValue2">this second input parameter</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object AsyncWithReturnValue(Func<object, object, object> funcFunction, object inputValue1, object inputValue2)
    {
        object returnValue = null;
        Form form = (MyObject as Form);
        form.Invoke(new Func<object, object,object>(delegate(object _object1,object _object2)
        {
            returnValue = funcFunction(_object1,_object2);
            return returnValue;
        }), inputValue1,inputValue2);
        return returnValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Three Parameters, With ReturnValue
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="funcFunction">the function needed to be delegated</param>
    /// <param name="inputValue1">the first input parameter</param>
    /// <param name="inputValue2">the second input parameter</param>
    /// <param name="inputValue3">the third input parameter</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object AsyncWithReturnValue(Func<object, object, object, object> funcFunction, object inputValue1, object inputValue2, object inputValue3)
    {
        object returnValue = null;
        Form form = (MyObject as Form);
        form.Invoke(new Func<object, object, object,object>(delegate(object _object1, object _object2,object _object3)
        {
            returnValue = funcFunction(_object1, _object2,_object3);
            return returnValue;
        }), inputValue1, inputValue2,inputValue3);
        return returnValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// One Parameter,WithOut ReturnValue
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionFunction">the function needed to be delegated</param>
    /// <param name="inputValue">the input prameter</param>
    public void AsyncWithOutReturnValue(Action<object> actionFunction, object inputValue)
    {
        Form form = (MyObject as Form);
        form.Invoke(new Action<object>(delegate(object _object)
        {
            actionFunction(_object);
        }),inputValue);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Two Parameters,WithOut ReturnValue
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionFunction">the function needed to be delegated</param>
    /// <param name="inputValue1">the first input parameter</param>
    /// <param name="inputValue2">the second input parameter</param>
    public void AsyncWithOutReturnValue(Action<object,object> actionFunction, object inputValue1,object inputValue2)
    {
        Form form = (MyObject as Form);
        form.Invoke(new Action<object,object>(delegate(object _object1,object _object2)
        {
            actionFunction(_object1,_object2);
        }), inputValue1,inputValue2);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Three Parameters, WithOut ReturnValue
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionFunction">the function needed to be delegated</param>
    /// <param name="inputValue1">the first input parameter</param>
    /// <param name="inputValue2">the second input paramter</param>
    /// <param name="inputValue3">the third input parameter</param>
    public void AsyncWithOutReturnValue(Action<object, object,object> actionFunction, object inputValue1, object inputValue2,object inputValue3)
    {
        Form form = (MyObject as Form);
        form.Invoke(new Action<object, object,object>(delegate(object _object1, object _object2,object _object3)
        {
            actionFunction(_object1, _object2,_object3);
        }), inputValue1, inputValue2,inputValue3);
    }
}
}
```

now I used the class like below:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AsyncLibAPP
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        asyncLib = new AsyncLibery.AsyncLib(this);
    }
    AsyncLibery.AsyncLib asyncLib;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void test()
    {
        button1.Text = "test";
    }
    private string test1()
    {
        label1.Text = "test";
        return "test";
    }
    private string test2(object value)
    {
        label1.Text = value.ToString();
        return "test,test";
    }
    private void test3(object s)
    {
        label1.Text = s.ToString();
    }
    private void test4(object s1, object s2, object s3)
    {
        label1.Text = s1.ToString() + s2.ToString() + s3.ToString();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //asyncLib.RunAsyncCrossThreads(test);
        //string value = asyncLib.AsyncWithNoParamOneReturnValue(test1).ToString();
        //string value = asyncLib.Async(test2,"aaaa").ToString();
       // MessageBox.Show(value);
        //asyncLib.AsyncWithOutReturnValue(test3,"sssss");
        asyncLib.AsyncWithOutReturnValue(test4,"aaaaaa","bbbbbbbb","cccccccc");
    }
}
}
```

It runs ok, but seems so ugly.

I planned to use `T` instead of `Object` type, but I don't know how to do this.

Can anyone optimize it? thx very much.

Comment: This might be a candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One aspect about this code that is indeed very ugly is the word "Async".  None of these methods are asynchronous, they are all synchronous calls that don't return until the invoked method has finished running.

But the biggest problem is that it just isn't necessary.  You got lambdas at your disposal, you only ever need *one* method.  A lambda can capture a variable.  Your test code is best written like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string value = "aaaaaa";
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => test4(value, "bbbbbbbb", "cccccccc")));
    }
```

With a fake *value* variable to avoid making it too trivial.  And keep in mind that you almost always want to use BeginInvoke(), making a worker thread block on the UI thread is not productive.  Except when you need a return value, then Invoke() is required.  Which is in itself almost always wrong, workers should be started with the arguments they need.  Whatever you get from a UI component by using Invoke() later is going to be pretty random since the worker is not in any way synchronized with the user's input.

Comment: Hi Passant, thx for your reply. If I need to run the function asynchronously, do I need to use BeginInvoke? is there any other class that can make the function asynchronously?  I know Action is a delegate and the Invoke() method can make the UI element cross threads. also Action does not delegate the function has return vlaue, If I Run a function with returnValue, need I use Func?  then How to use it? thx very much.  :)